# Dynamic Shared Library compilation with g++

Tags: c++, linux, g++, shared-libraries

I'm trying to compile the following simple DL library example code from [Program-Library-HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/dl-libraries.html) with g++.  This is just an example so I can learn how to use and write shared libraries.  The real code for the library I'm developing will be written in C++.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    void *handle;
    double (*cosine)(double);
    char *error;

    handle = dlopen ("/lib/libm.so.6", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        fputs (dlerror(), stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    cosine = dlsym(handle, "cos");
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fputs(error, stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf ("%f\n", (*cosine)(2.0));
    dlclose(handle);
}
```

If I compile the program with gcc it works fine.

```
gcc -o foo foo.c -ldl
```

When I change the filename and compiler to the following

```
g++ -o foo foo.cpp -ldl
```

I get the following error:

> foo.cpp:16: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'double (*)(double)'

I understand (I *think* I understand, correct me if this is wrong) that I can't do an implicit cast from a void pointer in C++, but C lets me, and this is why the above code will compile using gcc but not using g++.  So I tried an explicit cast by changing line 16 above to:

```
cosine = (double *)dlsym(handle, "cos");
```

With this in place, I get the following error:

> foo.cpp:16: error: cannot convert 'double*' to 'double (*)(double)' in assignment

These problems probably have more to do with my own general ignorance of proper C++ coding standards than anything else.  Can anyone point me to a good tutorial on developing dynamic libraries for Linux that uses C++ example code?

Comment: I'd suggest going through 'Thinking in C++' to get up to speed on C++. As you correctly spotted, you can't implicitly cast from void* to other pointers in C++, and that implies you really just need to get up to speed on C++ rather than the other areas :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm reading C++ Primer in my spare time, but right now I have a project due.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

C allows implicit casts from `void *` to any pointer type (including function pointers); C++ requires explicit casting. As leiflundgren says, you need to cast the return value of `dlsym()` to the function pointer type you need.

Many people find C's function pointer syntax awkward. One common pattern is to typedef the function pointer:

```
typedef double (*cosine_func_ptr)(double);
```

You can define your function pointer variable `cosine` as a member of your type:

```
cosine_func_ptr cosine;
```

And cast using the type instead of the awkward function pointer syntax:

```
cosine = (cosine_func_ptr)dlsym(handle, "cos");
```

Comment: I can't help thinking that you had to read my mind to figure out what my real problem was.  Thank you.  :)

Comment: Use reinterpret_cast<cosine_func_ptr>() rather than the C cast operator.

Answer (score 9):

`dlsym` returns a pointer to the symbol. (As `void*` to be generic.)
In your case you should cast it to a function-pointer.

```
 double (*mycosine)(double); // declare function pointer
 mycosine = (double (*)(double)) dlsym(handle, "cos"); // cast to function pointer and assign

 double one = mycosine(0.0); // cos(0)
```

So this one of these rare cases where the compiler error is a good clue. ;)

Comment: This works with double (*cosine)(double); from the original code, but not with the function pointer declaration you've provided.  As I'm the ignorant one asking questions here, I don't feel that I should change your code.  :)

Answer (score 0):

With the way your code if written, this is really more of a C question, but you can get this to will work in C++. I don't have a tutorial for you on Dynamic Shared Libraries (the web page you linked to seems fine), but here's how to fix your code in C++:

- declare my_cos to be a function that will (eventually) call the dynamically loaded cosine function:

  ```
  double my_cos(double);
  ```
- assign the function pointer to my_cos

  ```
  my_cos = (double (*)(double)) dlsym(handle, "cos");
  ```

This is a little complicated, but it's assigning to my_cos something that returns a double, is the result of dereferencing another function pointer, and takes a double as an argument. As other people have posted, C++ is a little more demanding about the explicitness of your code than C.

- replace that rather dated fputs message with a std::cerr or std::cout:

  ```
  std::cerr << "error loading library cos: " << error << std::endl;
  ```

and

```
std::cout << "result is " << (*my_cos)(2.0)) << std::endl;
```

Hope that this help. If that weird casty stuff scares you, I'd recommend Deep C Secrets by van Linden, and definitely the Kernighan and Ritchie Book on C.

Edit: Good point in the comment about how you're specifically looking for a development guide in C++ rather than C to avoid this type of problem. I don't know of a comparable guide in C++, but about 99% of C code can be embedded in C++ code and work just fine. This function pointer case is one of the exceptions.

Comment: The provided example code is C, but I'll be developing in C++, so I need to compile with g++.  The question might be naive, and the answer might be "Don't compile C code with g++." :)

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you have to perform a `reinterpret_cast` (not a C cast):

```
typedef double (* double_from_double_function_t(double));
…
double_from_double_function_t cosine = reinterpret_cast<double_from_double_function_t>(dlsym(handle, "cos"));
```