# Creating and Linking various Cpps together

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

i was thinking if it was possible to ***separately*** write programs and then use it in a single program
  my idea was to make a program for storing profiles and another program for game logic,..
  and then combine it ( or use it ) into a single program

Profile.cpp --------- **bridge.cpp**-------------game.cpp

where bridge will be used to access (and display )both the cpps

Comment: You probably want to take a look at [C++ Dynamic Shared Libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496664/c-dynamic-shared-library-on-linux).

Comment: @ netcoder if u can  provide me a basic documentation or tutorial  it would be great... i am just a beginner

Comment: I don't do in tutorials. If you want to use dynamic linking, learn C++ first.

Comment: ok! i will search up dynamic linking

Comment: When you learn a new technology, it is wise to start with the simplest example you can find. Programmers speak of "Hello World", the simplest program that works and does something, as the ideal first project. You should write a simple C++ program, `main()` and two other functions, verify that it works as intended, then split it into three source files ("bridge.cpp", "profile.cpp", "game.cpp") and try to compile and link them. Ideally you should use a simpler tool than turboC++ at first, but I'm sure the turboC++ docs describe this process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, C++ supports **separate compilation**, so you can write your program in pieces, in separate source files. You compile the files and link them together to create the executable file. The command line compiler can do it for you:

```
bcc bridge.cpp profile.cpp game.cpp
```

Comment: @SiddharthaSinha - it's the command line compiler for turboc++. If you're using the IDE, just put all the source files into the same project.

Comment: may i know the usage of creating a project

Comment: I haven't used turboc++ in years (although I used to work at Borland on compilers), but it's somewhere in the menus.