# How to call a class and its function present in so file from a C++ program in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, dynamic-linking, shared-objects, dynamic-library

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Dynamic Shared Library on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496664/c-dynamic-shared-library-on-linux)

I am writing a shared object say libtest.so which has a class and a function. I have another program say "Program.cpp" from which i want to call the class and its function present in the libtest.so file. I am clueless as to how to proceed. Please help.

Thanks
Regards
Mahesh

Comment: Dynamically (with `dlopen`), or statically? In the latter case just add `-ltest` to your `ld`.

Comment: I am trying dynamically with dlopen.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically, you need to call `dlsym` to get the address of the
function, and then call it through the pointer.  The syntax for this is
a bit tricky, since `dlsym` returns a `void*`, and there's no conversion
between `void*` and a pointer to function.  (Some compilers do allow it,
although formally, in pre C++11, it required a diagnostic, as does the C
standard.)  The solution recommended in the Posix standard is:

```
int (*fptr)( int );
*(void**)(&fptr) = dlsym( handle, "function_name" );
```

This supposes that pointers to functions have the same size and format
as pointers to data—not guaranteed by the C or C++ standards, but
guaranteed by Posix.

Comment: Hi James, Thank u for your response. Calling only a function from .so file is working. I want to call a function using the class object present in the .so file.

Comment: If it's a member function, just use `dlsym` to get the address of the object (a straight-forward cast from `void*` will do here), and call the function on it: `MyType* p = (MyType*)dlsym(...); p->function();`