# Calling Python code from Objective-C

Tags: python, objective-c, nsbundle

I am looking for the best way to call Python code from Objective-C program.
Few details:

- Python's code doesn't use PyObjC at all, just Python's basics.
- There are several Python's files with similar functionality each (aka “variations on a theme”).

## NSBundle

Encapsulating each *.py into *.bundle was the first thing that has came into mind.

PythonClass.py:

```
import objc
NSObject = objc.lookUpClass('NSObject')

class PythonClass(NSObject):
    def Function(self):
        print("Python is speaking!")
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2app

setup(
    plugin = ['PythonClass.py'],
)
```

Terminal command: `python setup.py py2app -s -p objc`

It works fine, but there are several problems:

- **Large *.bundle size**. Even though [Foundation is not imported](http://www.hardcoded.net/articles/embedded-pyobjc), and bundle is semi standalone (flag "-s"), the size of the *.bundle is ~1MB. Is there any other way to reduce the size?
- **PyObjC dependance**. Class doesn't use objc, but if we don't subclass `NSObject` then, on Objective-C side, `[bundle principalClass]` is `(Null)` and `PythonClass` cannot be instantiated. Is there a way to avoid using `NSObject` in *.py?

## CFBundle

I have also been thinking about using `CFBundle`, but `CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName(...)` always returns `NULL` (of course, in this case, *.py contains a function, not a class). I couldn't find any material on this matter. Maybe some of you are more lucky.

Is there a better way of embedding Python into Objective-C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Python/C API (a bridge between Python and C), C++ class (OOP layer for easier management) that calls Python code, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496664) method to put C++ class into CFBundle.

If necessary, this also works with Dynamic Library (*.dylib) instead of CFBundle.