# exporting a member function of application to be called by shared library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, symbols, qmainwindow, class-members

How could I export a C++ class function to be used with a shared library in Linux for sending continuous updates

I have an application C++ code which has a processing class function called `updateFcn`, I have to pass in updated structure data every ~100 milliseconds, from a shared library, I could not find the symbol for this class function when trying to access it with `dlsym`  but when I create a non-class extern function I was able to find the symbol for `externfunc` in my application and can call it through my shared library.

I want to export this class member :

```
void Myclass::updateFcn(mystruct& rf){
...
}
```

OR

I have an extern function in the same file `externfunc`(not a class member) which I could load it from the shared library. 
Note: I am not using `dlopen()` since the main executable with symbols exported is loaded into process address space.

```
extern "C" void externfunc(mystruct& rf){
...
}
```

how could I call the `updateFcn` from `externfunc` without creating a new instance of it each time (as this is a QT gui based application and lot of stuff happens in the constructor)

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: Btw, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496664/c-dynamic-shared-library-on-linux?rq=1) might be related.

Comment: @andreee, I looked at that, it creates an instance of the class each time the function is called, which i couldn't use on my side