# Using a shared library in another shared library

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, shared-libraries, shared-objects

I am creating a shared library from a class from an example I got here [C++ Dynamic Shared Library on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496664/c-dynamic-shared-library-on-linux). I would like to call another shared library from the shared library created and then use it in the main program. So I have the myclass.so library and I want to call another library say anotherclass.so from the myclass.so library and then use this myclass.so library in the main program. Any idea on how I can do this please.

Comment: A library does not use another library as such. You reference the header library of shared library a from library b. They can both be shared. Then, when you link your executable you include both so files in the link stage.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is more than one way in which multiple shared libraries may be added to
the linkage of a program, if you are building all the libraries, and the program,
yourself.

The elementary way is simply to explicitly add all of the libraries to the
the linkage of the program, and this is the usual way if you are building only the
program and linking libraries built by some other party.

If an object file `foo.o` in your linkage depends on a library `libA.so`, then
`foo.o` should precede `libA.so` in the linkage sequence. Likewise if `libA.so`
depends on `libB.so` then `libA.so` should precede `libB.so`. Here's an illustration.

We'll make a shared library `libsquare.so` from the files:

**square.h**

```
#ifndef SQUARE_H
#define SQUARE_H

double square(double d);

#endif
```

and

**square.cpp**

```
#include <square.h>
#include <cmath>

double square(double d)
{
    return pow(d,2);
}
```

Notice that the function `square` calls `pow`, which is declared in the
Standard header `<cmath>` and defined in the math library, `libm`.

Compile the source file `square.cpp` to a position-independent object file
`square.o`:

```
$ g++ -Wall -fPIC -I. -c square.cpp
```

Then link `square.o` into a shared library `libsquare.so`:

```
$ g++ -shared -o libsquare.so square.o
```

Next we'll make another shared library `libcube.so` from these files:

**cube.h**

```
#ifndef CUBE_H
#define CUBE_H

double cube(double d);

#endif
```

and

**cube.cpp**

```
#include <cube.h>
#include <square.h>

double cube(double d)
{
    return square(d) * d;
}
```

See that the function `cube` calls `square`, so `libcube.so` is going to
depend on `libsquare.so`. Build the library as before:

```
$ g++ -Wall -fPIC -I. -c cube.cpp
$ g++ -shared -o libcube.so cube.o
```

We haven't bothered to link `libsquare` with `libcube`, even though `libcube`
depends on `libsquare`, and even though we could have, since we're building `libcube`.
For that matter, we didn't bother to link `libm` with `libsquare`. By default the
linker will let us link a shared library containing undefined references, and it
is perfectly normal. It *won't* let us link a *program* with undefined references.

Finally let's make a program, using these libraries, from this file:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <cube.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << cube(3) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

First, compile that source file to `main.o`:

```
$ g++ -Wall -I. -c main.cpp
```

Then link `main.o` with all three required libraries, making sure to list
the linker inputs in dependency order: `main.o`, `libcube.so`, `libsquare.so`, `libm.so`:

```
$ g++ -o prog main.o -L. -lcube -lsquare -lm
```

`libm` is a system library so there's no need to tell the linker where to look for
it. But `libcube` and `libsquare` aren't, so we need to tell the linker to look for
them in the current directory (`.`), because that's where they are. `-L.` does that.

We've successfully linked `./prog`, but:

```
$ ./prog
./prog: error while loading shared libraries: libcube.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It doesn't run. That's because the runtime *loader* doesn't know where to find `libcube.so` (or `libsquare.so`, though it didn't get that far).

Normally, when we build shared libraries we then install them in one of the loader's default
search directories (the same ones as the linker's default search directories), where they're available to any program, so this wouldn't happen. But I'm not
going to install these toy libraries on my system, so as a workaround I'll prompt the loader where to look
for them by setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in my shell.

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
$ ./prog
27
```

Good. 3 cubed = 27.

Another and better way to link a program with shared libraries that aren't located
in standard system library directories is to link the program using the linker's
`-rpath=DIR` option. This will write some information into the executable to tell
the loader that it should search for required shared libraries in `DIR` before it tries
the default places.

Let's relink `./prog` that way (first deleting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from the shell so that it's not effective any more):

```
$ unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ g++ -o prog main.o -L. -lcube -lsquare -lm -Wl,-rpath=.
```

And rerun:

```
$ ./prog
27
```

To use `-rpath` with g++, prefix it with `-Wl`, because it's an option for linker, `ld`,
that the `g++` frontend doesn't recognise: `-Wl` tells `g++` just to pass the
option straight through to `ld`.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to add some points to the response of @Mike.

As you do not link **libcube** library with **libsquare** you are creating a sort of "incomplete library". When I say incomplete, I meant that when you link your application you must link it with both **libcube** and **libsquare** even though it does not use any symbol directly from **libsquare**.

It is better to link **libcube** directly with **libsquare**. This link will create the library with a NEEDED entry like:

```
readelf -d libcube.so
Tag        Type                         Name/Value
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libsquare.so]
```

Then when you link your application you can do:

```
g++ -o prog main.o -L. -lcube
```

Although, this will not link because the linker tries to locate the NEEDED library **libsquare**. You must precise its path by adding **-Wl,-rpath-link=.** to the linking command:

```
g++ -o prog main.o -L. -lcube -Wl,-rpath-link=.
```

Note: For runtime, you must still set **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** or link with **rpath** as mentioned by @Mike.

Comment: Тhis is a great addition to the initial explanation. I would only add that the best thing about this approach is that unresolved linkage would result in "shared not found" error rather than only "undefined reference to..." which is by far more informative...

Comment: @Minee thanks. But what if at the end I want only one big .so library (cube.so) that I send to third party (without libsquare.so)? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your library if you are using any other shared library so simply your library user is also dependent on that library. While creating library you can use -l  so the linker have notion for shared library and it will link when required.
But when you deliver your library as its dependent on some other library you need to export that too along with your and provide some environment variable or linker flag to load it from specified path (Your exported package). That will not lead any discrepancy other wise if its some standard library function user might get definition from his system's some other library and will lead in disastrous situation.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the library like you'd use it in any other application. You don't have to link to `anotherclass.so`, just to `myclass.so`.

However,  you will have to make both libraries (`myclass.so` **and** `anotherclass.so`) available for your later application's runtime. If one of them is missing you'll get runtime errors just like it is with any other application.